# Android - No tab titles in TabLayout?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I created a tablayout with viewpager and 3 fragments. When I run the application I can see correctly everything except of the tab titles that do not show, what am I missing?

My code in mainactivity.oncreate:

```
tabLayout=findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager= findViewById((R.id.view_pager));
        final ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter= new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(RulesFragment.getInstance(), "TREE RULES");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(TreeFragment.getInstance(), "REGRESSION TREE");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(PredictionFragment.getInstance(), "PREDICTION");
        rulesFragment= (RulesFragment) viewPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
        treeFragment= (TreeFragment) viewPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
        predictionFragment= (PredictionFragment) viewPagerAdapter.getItem(2);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorAnimationDuration="1000"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:tabIndicatorGravity="top"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabBackground="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I get:
[image]

In .xml I added the viewpager and the tablayout only, I didn't add any textview or other things for the tab titles since I thought it would do that automatically with tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager). Is it wrong?

Comment: Share xml file.

Comment: Added it @bilal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement getPageTitle inside your ViewPagerAdapter!

Like-

```
 // Returns the page title for the top indicator
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;
        }
```

Reference you can check -

https://guides.codepath.com/android/viewpager-with-fragmentpageradapter

Also, your ViewPagerAdapter should not hold onto a `List<Fragment>` as that will cause crashes after process death in production. The correct way to implement a FragmentPagerAdapter is:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0) return new RulesFragment();
        if(position == 1) return new TreeFragment();
        if(position == 2) return new PredictionFragment();

        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if(position == 0) return "TREE RULES";
        if(position == 1) return "REGRESSION TREE";
        if(position == 2) return "PREDICTION";
      
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
    }
}
```

To get a reference to a Fragment created by a ViewPager, use the following `findFragmentByTag` scheme:

```
Fragment fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + viewPager.getId() + ":" + fragmentPosition)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had already overrid it but I returned empty string because I had to edit it but I forgot :D